# Can't resolve symbol R in "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image: import android.R]

[image: Error]

I have imported the project from github and I am getting this error repeatedly. I can open my previous projects and run them on my phone but I can't do the same with this project. The "Gradle Build Running" runs forever. I have read through the answers regarding the same and I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

`android.R` is the wrong import.

You should import `com.example.android.miwok.R`.

If that cannot be resolved, then `R.java` is not being generated.

Possible options

1. You need to build your project in order to generate that file.
2. You have some error elsewhere (usually in a XML resource file).

> The "Gradle Build Running" runs forever.

A slow internet will cause this. When you first start a project, all the dependencies and Gradle binaries for the project need to be downloaded.

Comment: import com.example.android.miwok.R; is shown as unused import.

Comment: So? Does the project run or not?

Comment: "Gradle Build Running" this runs forever and I couldn't use "Clean Project" or "Rebuild Project"

Comment: I don't really know what to tell you, but that is a completely separate problem than `R` not resolving. You are welcome to try to build your app from the command line, outside of the IDE

Comment: Can you pass the info regarding the same?

Comment: In the project directory, you can run `.\gradlew`, that should print out the tasks that are available to run. `clean` and `build` are usually good

Comment: The ERROR is resolved now as I reinstalled Android studio. Thanks for the help!